# What is the most basic object that can make use of addEventListener in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm making a **handler** class that will read similar to this:

```
package avian.background
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import avian.objects.AvChild;
    import avian.background.AvManager;

    public class AvHandler extends EventDispatcher
    {
        // vars
        private var _last:uint = 0;
        private var _time:uint = 0;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function AvHandler()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
            _last = getTimer();
        }

        /**
         * Called on dispatch of Event.ENTER_FRAME
         */
        private function _handle(e:Event):void
        {
            _time = getTimer() - _last;

            var i:AvChild;
            for each(i in AvManager.getList("all"))
            {
                i.step(_time);
            }

            _last = getTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to have this class extend the most basic class possible that can still make use of `addEventListener()` - for some reason the ENTER_FRAME even never fires - works fine if it were to extend **Sprite** or **MovieClip**. I've wrongly assumed that EventDispatcher was the most basic possible.

I originally had the event applied to the stage which I parsed through the constructor - this just seemed quite untidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest Class that FIRES the Event.ENTER_FRAME is DisplayObject

Comment: Thanks mate - had a look into it.

Comment: Can you confirm you can actually extend from DisplayObject and instantiate your AvHandler class without runtime errors? I don't think DisplayObject can be instantiated directly, but I don't personally know if it's safe to instantiate as soon as you extend it one level down (without any setup required).

Comment: It may have some level of 'abstract-detection' in the native code for DisplayObject, which could be replicated in AS3 as: if(Object(this).constructor==YourAbstractClass) { //ERROR! }

Answer (score 0):

DisplayObject is the most basic object to fire ENTER_FRAME.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event:enterFrame